# Change PostgreSQL service Name - Linux

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, postgresql-10, service-name

I have two different PostgreSQL 10 servers running on the same system (using different ports) on a CentOS 6/7 system. Can someone tell me how to name these PostgreSQL services differently? Like when I run a `ps` on the system, it should show both the services running with different names. Right now it shows both the service names as `postgres`. Can someone tell me how to rename the postgres service on Linux?

I know how to do that on Windows `pg_ctl.exe register -N Postgres_1`  (The -N argument lets us choose the name of the Postgres service) So basically when we register the service, we can give it a custom name on Windows... but can someone tell me how to do the same on Linux?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you set `cluster_name` in `postgresql.conf`, you will see it in the `args` column of the `ps` output.

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz. Is there a way to change the process name completely?

Comment: Not unless you want to hack PostgreSQL. But I fail to see how `cluster_name` could not be sufficient.

Comment: Got it.. Thanks again for your help @Laurenz

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the service name (you must know the service name), then here you go-

Browse to the service location and rename it, like this:
On Centos 6 :

```
cd /etc/init.d/
mv postgresql postgresql5432
```

On Centos 7:

```
cd /usr/lib/systemd/system
mv postgresql.service postgresql5432.service
systemctl daemon-reload
```

(I am assuming you know what service is using port no. 5432)

But if you want to just figure out using ps then go for the solution of @Laurenz Albe.